# How to show angular material auto-complete all items even one item is selected?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Angular material default functionality is when user selects  one item from auto-completion list remaining items are not showing.

Eg: When I click on the control it's showing like this
[image]

After one item selected it is not showing remaining list.

[image]

Here I wanna show all auto-complete items even user selects one items from the list.

Is this possible with angular material? If yes could you please help how can we achieve this.

I need output like this(Below image I edited in paint).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about basic example from https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete, just try:

```
md-items="item in ctrl.states"
```

instead of

```
md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
```

because of controller filter the initial list in

```
results = query ? self.states.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : self.states
```

Comment: This is not working already tried.
Here I need even when user select  the any one item from the list it should show all items from the list and selected Item should be selected as it is

Comment: @kernallora Please check this quick codepen snippet http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWVvzd -- it works as expected, here is a screenshot http://static.xscreenshot.com/2017/02/28/17/screen_9a6af5f03f5de16c5be241ed1365f600

Comment: Seems to be you understood something which is not needed for me.
can you please check my last screen in my question
In that  item already selected named 'Alabama' but still all items are showing in the auto-complete drop down

Comment: @kernallora Yes, my solution provides exactly what you want. Have you tried? Just type "Alabama" and you'll see that all items are showing in the auto-complete drop down.

Comment: No, your solution is not working as I needed.
Scenario: Select "Alabama"(As soon as I selects dropdown will be closed).
Again if I click  on the dropdown it is not showing the dropdown elements.
I need to show all element in the dropdown even user already selects value

Comment: @kernallora Well, now I understand your wishes. My code works when you *type* Alabama, not click on the item. Sorry, seems the required behavior could be reached only with your own component based on md-autocomplete.

Comment: I have no idea how to achieve this. Could you please help me this.